# A variation of a 'leaky bucket' problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking at a 'leaky bucket' problem with a few differences, the system is set up as follows:

1. the tank has a practically unlimited capacity
2. water is added with a known flow rate
3. periodically the drain valve is adjusted so that all of the water is drained over say 10 seconds
4. we are interested to know how much water is contained at time $t$

To give a concrete example, lets assume the water is added with a rate of 10L per second, every 4 seconds the drain is adjusted. When the drain is adjusted it is adjusted to $\frac{1}{10}$ of current volume of water.

Initially I started with the following diff. eq. $dV=I-\frac{1}{10}V$ where $V$ stands for volume and $I$ is the incoming flow rate in L per sec. The issue is that in this equation the drain is constant with respect to volume, whereas in the actual problem the drain is adjusted periodically and in between those events the water is draining with a set flow rate.

I have a feeling it involves using a $\sin$ function to model the period, but I'm not certain as to how to go about it.

Comment: When you say the drain is adjusted every $4$ second, it is adjusted to $V/10$ per second where $V$ is the volume of water in the tank at the time of adjusting the drain? So basically it is being reset to $V/10$ every $4$ second and in between it flows out at the previously adjusted rate?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the drain is adjusted every $\Delta t$ seconds. Let $V_n$ be the volume of water in the tank at $t=n\Delta t$. Let $t\in(n\Delta t,(n+1)\Delta t)$.$$\begin{align*}\frac{dV}{dt}=I-V_n/10\implies&V(t)-V_n=(t-n\Delta t)(I-V_n/10)\\\implies&V(t)=V_n(1+n\Delta t/10-t/10)+(t-n\Delta t)I\end{align*}$$We need to find an expression for $V_n$. The volume varies continuously so$$V_{n+1}=\lim_{t\to(n+1)\Delta t^-}V(t)=V_n[1-\Delta t/10]+I\Delta t$$

This is a first order non-homogeneous linear recurrence with constant coefficients whose solution is $$V_n=(V_0-10I)(1-\Delta t/10)^n+10I$$

Substituting $n=\lfloor t/\Delta t\rfloor$,$$V(t)=\left[\left(V_0-10I\right)\left(1-\frac{\Delta t}{10}\right)^{\lfloor t/\Delta t\rfloor}+10I\right]\left[1-\left(\frac{t-\lfloor t/\Delta t\rfloor\Delta t}{10}\right)\right]+I(t-\lfloor t/\Delta t\rfloor\Delta t)$$

---

Attached graph of $V(t)$ for $V_0=0,I=10,\Delta t=4$. Notice that the curve is piecewise linear as expected. The limiting value is $10I$.

[image: Graph]

Comment: That solution seems wrong to me, it looks as if the volume in the tank 'drops' every $\Delta t$ seconds, which shouldn't happen, the rate should change (ie. the slope) but the volume shouldn't have jump discontinuities.

Comment: @JohanStruus Oh my god. It seems I have misinterpreted the question. I understood it as "the drain is opened after every $4$ seconds and brings the volume down to one tenth of current volume and is then closed". Is the drain allowed to stay open during the entire duration?

Comment: That is correct, the drain is always open, you can just imagine that the 'hole' gets increased or decreased based on the volume in the tank at the time of the adjustment.

Comment: I will amend my solution then.

Comment: That works out thank you. As an aside I recall your previous answer which although didn't answer the question at the time is pertinent to an extension. Specifically if in addition to the above every some other interval of time $\Delta T$ the volume of water gets halved (this is where the previous answer comes in) how would that modify the equation?

Comment: If the drain is open for the entire duration and after $\Delta t$ seconds the volume is halved and then the drain readjusted, take $V_n$ to be the volume immediately after $t=n\Delta t$ i.e. after the halving. Everything remains same but for a factor of $2$ in the recurrence:$$2V_{n+1}=V_n[1-\Delta t/10]+I\Delta t$$Note that in my last answer, I assumed the volume was instantaneously reduced after every $\Delta t$ seconds (halving action) but didn't provide for the continuous draining action. If you are interested in this type of problem, you can look at edit 3 in edit history of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Say volume of water at $t = 0$ is $V_0$.

Volume of water at time $t = 4n$ where $n \in 0, \mathbb{Z+}$ is then given by

$\displaystyle V_{4n} = \bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)^n V_0 + 10I \bigg(1 - \bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)^n \bigg)$

And volume of water at time $4n+t$ is given by,

$\displaystyle V_{4n+t} = V_{4n} \bigg(1 - \frac{t}{10}\bigg) + I \, t$ where $0 \leq t \leq 4$

Here is how the expression comes (wherever I write $t$, it is $0 \leq t \leq 4$) -

$V_t = V_0 - \frac{V_0}{10}t + I \, t$

$V_4 = V_0 - \frac{4V_0}{10} + 4I = \frac{3}{5}V_0 + 4I$

$\displaystyle V_{4+t} = V_4 - \frac{V_4}{10}t + I \, t$

i.e. $\displaystyle V_{4+t} = \frac{3}{5}V_0 + 4I - \frac{t}{10}(\frac{3}{5}V_0 + 4I) + I \, t$

i.e. $\displaystyle V_{4+t} = \frac{3}{5}V_0 (1 - \frac{t}{10})+ (4 + \frac{3t}{5})I$

$\therefore \displaystyle V_{8} = (\frac{3}{5})^2 V_0+ 4(1 + \frac{3}{5})I$

Similarly, $\displaystyle V_{12} = (\frac{3}{5})^3 V_0 + 4(1 + \frac{3}{5} + (\frac{3}{5})^2)I$

At $t = 4n$, the geometric series $\, 1 + \frac{3}{5} + ... + (\frac{3}{5})^{n-1} = \displaystyle \frac{1 - (\frac{3}{5})^{n}}{1 - \frac{3}{5}} = \frac{5}{2} (1 - (\frac{3}{5})^{n})$

And this leads to expression at time $4n$ and $4n + t$.

Comment: As there is a discrete increase or decrease every $4$ seconds and it is not a smooth curve, you will only be able to differentiate in the interval $0 \leq t \leq 4$ starting at any time $4n$. $ \frac {d V_{4n+t}} {dt} = I - \frac{V_{4n}} {10}$

Comment: So if I were to generalise it, with $k$={period of adjustment} and $j$={how long it takes the tank to drain at specific volume} then $\displaystyle V_{kn}=(\frac{j-k}{j})^n*V_0+j*I*(1-(\frac{j-k}{j})^n)$?

Comment: @JohanStruus yes that looks alright. LHS will be $V_{kn}$.

Comment: OK I see LHS is already $V_{kn}$. I thought $k$ was missing... too small for my eyes :) missed it.